# android studio multiple modules requiring the same android-support-v4.jar but proguard report duplicate

Tags: java, android, jar, dependencies

In my Android Studio project, I have an Android module *app*, and two library projects *lib1* and *lib2*.

All these 3 modules require the same file dependency: android-support-v4.jar.

When I only put this jar in *app*, *lib1* will report an error that "package android.support.v4.view doesn't exist", meaning it didn't find android-support-v4.jar. When I put this jar all the 3 modules, proguard will report an error of duplicate classes found. So how can I let multiple modules referring to the same jar library? Thanks!

Note that I've got to use jar file instead of remote library in maven repository, since another developer is using eclipse on this project.

Comment: don't put `android-support-v4.jar` file in each of 3 libraries. Just put `android-support-v4.jar` in your main project `libs` folder and compile that `jar` in your main project `build.gradle`.